# A couple small basic questions making issues

Tags: java

*Edited. I ended up with the following.

I was given this code.

```
package lab2;
/**
* Model of a basketball for use in quality control simulations.
*/
public class Basketball 
/**
* Inflation status of this Basketball.
*/

private boolean isInflated;
/**
* Diameter of this Basketball.
*/
private double diameter;
/**
* Constructs an uninflated Basketball with the given diameter.
* @param givenDiameter 
*   the diameter for this Basketball
*/
public Basketball(double givenDiameter)
{
isInflated = false;
diameter = givenDiameter;
}

/**
* Returns the diameter of this Basketball.
* @return
*   diameter of this Basketball
*/
public double getDiameter()
{
return diameter;
}

/**
* Determines whether this Basketball can be dribbled.
* @return
*   true if the basketball is inflated, false otherwise
*/
public boolean isDribbleable()
{
// can be dribbled only if it is inflated
return isInflated;
}

/**
* Returns the circumference of this Basketball.
* @return
*   circumference of this Basketball
*/
public double getCircumference()
{
// PI times the diameter
double result = Math.PI * diameter;
return result;
}

/**
* Inflates this Basketball.
*/
public void inflate()
{
isInflated = true;
}
}
```

The only change I did was chaning the Basketball class to

```
 public class Basketball extends java.lang.Object
```

Then I wrote the following code and saved it in the same folder as the the one above.

```
public class BasketballTest  {
public static void main (String[] args){

Basketball b;
b = new Basketball(4.0);
System.out.println(b.getDiameter());
}
}
```

The first code compiles fine, but when compiling the second I get the following error.

```
BasketballTest.java:5: error: cannot access Basketball
Basketball b;
^
bad class file: .\Basketball.class
class file contains wrong class: lab2.Basketball
Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
1 error
```

I hope someone help understanding where the problems are. I am not in a class, but doing this assignment to learn Java. 
The link to the assignment http://www.briannakayama.com/COMS227/Labs/Lab2/

Thanks

Comment: Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to understand the guidelines for posting on StackOverflow. Hint: This is not a tutorial, discussion or homework help site.

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include 1) a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and 2) a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. 1) is 5 lines of code. What more did you do?

Comment: Edit the title of your Question to actually describe something of its technical nature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, format your code well. Second, I don't see your link. Lastly, these kind of questions are not for stack overflow but I'll answer it anyway.

1. Package is basically like a folder that classes and other files are stored. Project is the whole thing - group of packages. You are good with what you have.
2. You didn't specified what kind of error this is.... BUT I'm guessing you probably didn't make basketball class. Or put correct constructor in basketball class. Or.... I don't know. Tell me what your error it is.
3. OH now I see it.
   You were suppose to put that file in same folder as the basketballTest class. If don't, that will give you an error.(because compt have no idea what basketball is) Or you can make a whole new class and just copy the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The link is here if you want to take a look.http://www.briannakayama.com/COMS227/Labs/Lab2/page1.php

The reason I posted it here that it is not homework for me since I am /will not take the class. 

Finally, in page 1 of the lab, it talks about question 3, but it I can't understand if they want me to just do it within BaxketballTest or Basketball. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I edited the post, and posted my new codes. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

1) Consider project as a directory (eg: C Drive), package as a folder in the drive and class as .java file.

2). I don't know what do you mean by `Basketball b;`as `Basketball` is not a data type and looking at the line below you are trying to assign it float value.

Probably you need something like this,

```
public class BasketballTest
{
  double b;

  BasketballTest() //Constructor
  {
    this.b = 4.0;
  }

  void display(){System.out.println(b);}

  public static void main (String [] args){

      BasketballTest obj = new BasketballTest();
      obj.display();

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I edited the post, and posted my new codes. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't have Basketball class inside your folder. Check your folder positions and your package declarations.
And for the question, I believe that it wants you to make variable 'b' to execute  method to change isInflated to true; I'm not sure about your homework link. If you know what you are suppose to do, I can help you with that.

Comment: P.S. That error happens because tester class cannot reach Basketball class. Also, I think you don't need to extend java.lang.object....